# Google ChromeでJavascriptのみでChromeアカウントのストレージにデータを記録する方法

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome

HTMLおよびJavascript・jQueryで自作の統計記録ページを作成し、数値を変更するごとにChromeのローカルストレージに記録するようにプログラムを組みました（以下のようなもの）

```js
$('input[name="hoge"]').change( function(){
  localStorage.setItem("hoge", $(this).val())
})
```

しかし、別のパソコンでも同じ統計記録の閲覧・変更を行いたいと思い、ローカルストレージではなくChromeアカウントに紐づけられたストレージに統計記録を保存する機能を、Chrome拡張機能を使わずJavascriptのみで作りたいと思います。
どなたか方法をご存知であればご教示願います。

Answer (score 1):

GoogleのFirebaseなんてどうでしょうか。
この記事が参考になりそうです。
https://qiita.com/kohashi/items/43ea22f61ade45972881

他にもGoogle Spreadsheetに書き込むなんてこともできますし、Google Driveの中にファイルを保存するという方法もあります。
正直言って、やり方は無数にありますよ。